# Store multiple values in one db column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create a pivot table to help keep track of "challenges" in my applications. Basically I have a `challenge_task` pivot table that creates a relationship between a challenge and a task. When a user that is in a challenge completes a task I want to be able to tell so I can track a user's progress. How is the best way to store multiple users completing a task on a challenge?

I was thinking in the pivot table adding a `json` column called `user_completed` to handle this and store the `user_id` for every user that completes the task for a challenge.

So `challenge_task` would look like

```
challenge_id | task_id | user_completed
```

Is this a good way? Or is there anything that fits this better?

Comment: "multiple values in one db column" is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @Uueerdo if a challenge only will have two users then should I do like a `user_a_completed` and `user_b_completed` column on the pivot table and add the `user_id` for when a user completes them

Comment: Just make a new row each time. No need to store multiple user id's in one row.

Comment: You can use `json` columns in MySQL past a certain version (don't remember the number) but from my experience, this was more of a hinderance than a help. Querying `json` columns is a bit messy and not really supported yet by Laravel, any benefits added by them were quickly replaced by other issues, etc. The eloquent model/relationship system also works wonders for decreasing complexity when querying/return results with one-to-many or many-to-many relationships. In the end, up to you.

Comment: As #Uueerdo and #Brian Glaz said

Comment: Why the need to link challenges and tasks? Can the same task be a part of multiple challenges? If one is, and a user completes it, should it satisfy both challenges?

Comment: @Uueerdo correct a task can belong to many challenges since there are some predefined ones

Comment: @Packy ...and if a user completes that task, does it complete it for all challenges that have the task, or just one of them?

Comment: @Uueerdo just that specific challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a database structure something like this:

```
challenge: challenge_id | other data
task: task_id | other data
user: user_id | other  data

challenge_task: challenge_task_id | challenge_id | task_id 
               | possibly more data (such as deadline for completion)

challenge_task_users: challenge_task_id | user_id
                     | possibly more data (such as status: accepted, in progress, completed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont recommend Json if you want to index your data, because Json can not be indexed.
I think you should make a pivot table between the users and the tasks too, and create the neccesary relations.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend you inserting multiple values in one database column.

---

**Note: This is my opinion. Just sharing the way I use it.**

A table called tasks_settings which has the task settings.

[image: Example 1]

I find this way flexible because I can always edit the title, description, and reward easily. I can also add 2 more fields here which are valid_till and valid_for. So you can make it expire after a period of time and only for a special rank like staff or all users.

**Another table called users_tasks**

[image: Example 2]

This one controls the users. Whether they have completed the task or not. This could also achieve what you are looking for.

```
id | challenge_id | task_id | username | user_completed
```

I hope this has helped you!